# I want to use a signal which emitt just after log out in django allauth, just like user_logged_in

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to use a django all auth signal which emit just after log out, just like `user_logged_in`, but I didn't find any signal for log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just use the core Django signal from django.contrib.auth, user_logged_out?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out

Good luck!

Comment: Could you mark the answer correct if it helped you out for anyone else looking?